How to setup active-backup bond on Ubuntu server 24.04 using netplan?
I have two public static IP addresses from two separate ISP on two interfaces and I want setup active-backup solution on VM which as soon as my primary Interface fails it switches to backup network.
I searched trough documentations, blogs and AI chat bots and here is my yml configuration, but still can't access Internet.
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
    ens34:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
  bonds:
    bond0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      interfaces:
        - ens33
        - ens34
      addresses:
        - 5.160.160.162/29
        - 5.200.200.202/29
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 8.8.8.8
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 5.160.160.161
          metric: 100
        - to: default
          via: 5.200.200.201
          metric: 200
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
        primary: ens33

I even tried routing-policy to avoid default route configuration conflict but that didn't work either.
# same as above

      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 5.160.160.161
          table: 100
        - to: default
          via: 5.200.200.201
          table: 200
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
        primary: ens33
  routing-policy:
    - table: 100
      priority: 100
    - table: 200
      priority: 200

Here is my ip and routing commands for more info:

After hours of testing and debugging I managed to fix IP addresses and now I can ssh into my server and even active-backup on disabling interfaces works, but I couldn't fix the outgoing routes!
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens33:
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
        ens34:
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
        ens35:
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
    bonds:
        bond0:
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
            interfaces:
                - ens33
                - ens34
            parameters:
                mode: active-backup
                primary: ens33
                mii-monitor-interval: 5000
            addresses:
                - 5.160.160.162/29
                - 5.200.200.202/29
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                    - 1.1.1.1
                    - 8.8.8.8
            routes:
                - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                  via: 5.160.160.161
                  on-link: true
                  metric: 100
                  table: 100
                - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                  via: 5.200.200.201
                  on-link: true
                  metric: 200
                  table: 200
            
            routing-policy:
                - from: 5.160.160.162/29
                  table: 100
                  priority: 100
                - from: 5.200.200.202/29
                  table: 200
                  priority: 200
                - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                  table: 100
                - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                  table: 200


When I disconnect the interfaces, even though it switches to another network correctly and I can ssh into the machine, the server has no internet because it is still trying to connect to the internet from the previous address (which was disconnected).

P.S: I just changed this IP addresses but other configs are the same
Thank you mpboden for your answer, I have tested your solutions, I copy your first answer and just change the IP and Gateway addresses for each interface.
I had this issue on your first method with bind using netplan --debug apply, here is the log:
netplan --debug try
** (process:19537): DEBUG: 08:02:44.101: starting new processing pass
** (process:19537): DEBUG: 08:02:44.102: bond0: adding new route
** (process:19537): DEBUG: 08:02:44.102: bond0: adding new route
** (process:19537): DEBUG: 08:02:44.102: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (process:19537): DEBUG: 08:02:44.102: ens35: setting default backend to 1
** (process:19537): DEBUG: 08:02:44.102: Configuration is valid
** (process:19537): DEBUG: 08:02:44.102: ens34: setting default backend to 1
** (process:19537): DEBUG: 08:02:44.102: Configuration is valid
** (process:19537): DEBUG: 08:02:44.102: bond0: setting default backend to 1
** (process:19537): DEBUG: 08:02:44.102: Configuration is valid
** (process:19537): DEBUG: 08:02:44.102: ens33: setting default backend to 1
** (process:19537): DEBUG: 08:02:44.102: Configuration is valid
DEBUG:Merged config:
b''
bond0: reverting custom parameters for bridges and bonds is not supported

Please carefully review the configuration and use 'netplan apply' directly.

If you pay attention to my second yml config, the routes and routing-policy are indented along bonds but in your config they are under bond0 section.
On the other hand, on your second solution, It works, but for the first ISP, when I disable first network interface from ESXi VM Settings it immediately switches to second network but it doesn't have Internet, even don't have it's own network gateway. I switch the order of ISPs and this time the same scenario happens again I had Internet from first ISP but when I disable the network it switch to second network but with no Internet.
This is a picture of tcpdump from ISP1 and ISP2 and as you can see there is no response from second network no mater what order I use (primary ISP1 -> secondary ISP2 or primary ISP2 -> secondary ISP1) I don't have a response from it.


I'll outline how to set this up in two ways. One configuration is how you want to do it with a bond interface and multiple IP address. The other is without a bond interface and just to the two interfaces, each with their own IP address.

Netplan config with a bond interface
I tested this with a VM in VirtualBox with two interfaces, each on different subnets, 10.0.2.0/24 and 10.0.3.0/24.
The following Netplan .yaml file works. It's basically the same as yours but without the on-link option for each route. Notice that the metric for the route to 10.0.2.2 is 100 and for 10.0.3.2 it's 200. A lower value takes precedence.
$ sudo cat 00-custom-config.yaml 
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
  bonds:
    bond0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      interfaces: [enp0s3, enp0s8]
      addresses:
        - 10.0.2.10/24
        - 10.0.3.10/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
        mii-monitor-interval: 100
        primary: enp0s3
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 10.0.2.2
          metric: 100
          table: 100
        - to: default
          via: 10.0.3.2
          metric: 200
          table: 200
      routing-policy:
        - from: 10.0.2.10
          table: 100
          priority: 100
        - from: 10.0.3.10
          table: 200
          priority: 200
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          table: 100
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          table: 300

The bond0 interface has both IP addresses as defined:
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:8c:35:70 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:56:6b:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/eter 36:a3:66:28:36:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.10/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global bond0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.0.3.10/24 brd 10.0.3.255 scope global bond0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::34a3:66ff:fe28:36e3/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

The routes generated from Netplan are as follows:
$ ip route
default via 10.0.2.2 dev bond0 proto kernel scope lin src 10.0.2.10
default via 10.0.3.2 dev bond0 proto kernel scope lin src 10.0.3.10

$ ip route show table all
default via 10.0.2.2 dev bond0 table 100 proto static metric 100
default via 10.0.3.2 dev bond0 table 200 proto static metric 200
10.0.2.0/24 dev bond0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.10
10.0.3.0/24 dev bond0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.10
local 10.0.2.10 dev bond0 table local proto kernel scope host src 10.0.2.10
broadcast 10.0.2.255 dev bond0 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.10
local 10.0.3.10 dev bond0 table local proto kernel scope host src 10.0.3.10
broadcast 10.0.3.255 dev bond0 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.10
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev bond0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
local 1 dev lo table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local fe80::34a3:66ff:fe28:36e3 dev bond0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
multicast ff00::/8 dev bond0 table local proto kernel metric 256 pref medium

If I run traceroute 8.8.8.8, you'll see that the first hop is 10.0.2.2, which is the gateway with the lower metric value of 100.
$ traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (10.0.2.2)  0.443 ms  0.382 ms  0.356 ms
 2  172.23.123.1 (172.23.123.1)  6.054 ms  6.024 ms  5.999 ms
 3  usa-67-224-97-97.sohonet.co.uk (67.224.97.97)  8.575 ms  12.017 ms  9.610 ms
 4  usa-173-0-160-145.sohonet.com (173.0.160.145)  6.469 ms  5.697 ms  5.656 ms
 5  soho185-116-57-52.sohonet.co.uk (185.116.57.52)  7.052 ms  5.586 ms  6.975 ms
 6  usa-67-224-111-33.sohonet.co.uk (67.224.111.33)  5.510 ms  7.741 ms  7.680 ms
 7  usa-67-224-111-32.sohonet.co.uk (67.224.111.32)  7.650 ms  6.140 ms  6.063 ms
 8  usa-67-224-111-10.sohonet.co.uk (67.224.111.10)  6.016 ms  5.982 ms  6.013 ms
 9  * * *
10  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  5.707 ms  5.672 ms  5.645 ms

Running a tcpdump on both interfaces prior to the traceroute shows traffic on enp0s3 and nothing onenp0s8.
$ sudo tcpdump -i enp0s3 
04:32:18.667564 IP server.59797 > dns.google.33434: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.667648 IP server.59206 > dns.google.33435: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.667681 IP server.46550 > dns.google.33436: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.667708 IP server.57827 > dns.google.33437: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.667739 IP server.50726 > dns.google.33438: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.667775 IP server.34804 > dns.google.33439: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.667814 IP server.60441 > dns.google.33440: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.667861 IP server.34329 > dns.google.33441: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.667911 IP server.57249 > dns.google.33442: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.667943 IP server.53318 > dns.google.33443: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.667981 IP server.55997 > dns.google.33444: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.668002 IP 10.0.2.2 > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 36
04:32:18.668002 IP 10.0.2.2 > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 36
04:32:18.668003 IP 10.0.2.2 > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 36
04:32:18.668012 IP server.37671 > dns.google.33445: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.668042 IP server.59027 > dns.google.33446: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.668082 IP server.43649 > dns.google.33447: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.668125 IP server.40522 > dns.google.33448: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.668168 IP server.49582 > dns.google.33449: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.668784 IP server.55502 > dns.google.domain: 2525+ [1au] PTR? 2.2.0.10.in-addr.arpa. (50)
04:32:18.672588 IP 172.23.123.1 > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
04:32:18.672588 IP 172.23.123.1 > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
04:32:18.673736 IP 172.23.123.1 > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
04:32:18.674923 IP usa-173-0-160-145.sohonet.com > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
04:32:18.674923 IP usa-173-0-160-145.sohonet.com > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
04:32:18.676805 IP soho185-116-57-52.sohonet.co.uk > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 152
04:32:18.676805 IP usa-67-224-97-97.sohonet.co.uk > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 40
04:32:18.676805 IP soho185-116-57-52.sohonet.co.uk > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 152
04:32:18.676806 IP soho185-116-57-52.sohonet.co.uk > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 152
04:32:18.677148 IP usa-67-224-97-97.sohonet.co.uk > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 40
04:32:18.677450 IP usa-173-0-160-145.sohonet.com > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
04:32:18.677450 IP usa-67-224-111-33.sohonet.co.uk > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
04:32:18.678242 IP dns.google.domain > server.55502: 2525 NXDomain 0/0/1 (50)
04:32:18.678567 IP server.55502 > dns.google.domain: 2525+ PTR? 2.2.0.10.in-addr.arpa. (39)
04:32:18.679411 IP usa-67-224-97-97.sohonet.co.uk > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 40
04:32:18.681777 IP dns.google.domain > server.55502: 2525 NXDomain 0/0/0 (39)
04:32:18.682464 IP server.59293 > dns.google.33450: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.682606 IP server.53679 > dns.google.33451: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.682639 IP server.53084 > dns.google.33452: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.683046 IP server.46600 > dns.google.domain: 1760+ [1au] PTR? 1.123.23.172.in-addr.arpa. (54)
04:32:18.685892 IP usa-67-224-111-33.sohonet.co.uk > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
04:32:18.685892 IP usa-67-224-111-32.sohonet.co.uk > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
04:32:18.685892 IP usa-67-224-111-33.sohonet.co.uk > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
04:32:18.687742 IP dns.google.domain > server.46600: 1760 NXDomain 0/0/1 (54)
04:32:18.688079 IP server.46600 > dns.google.domain: 1760+ PTR? 1.123.23.172.in-addr.arpa. (43)
04:32:18.690805 IP dns.google.domain > server.46600: 1760 NXDomain 0/0/0 (43)
04:32:18.692857 IP server.48459 > dns.google.33453: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.692929 IP server.38045 > dns.google.33454: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.692967 IP server.47477 > dns.google.33455: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.692998 IP server.48665 > dns.google.33456: UDP, length 32
04:32:18.693025 IP server.54143 > dns.google.3345

$ sudo tcpdump -i enp0s8

To simulate the interface going down, I can uncheck the Cable Connected box within VirtualBox for the first interface, which is enp0s3:

After hitting "OK", the interface will be down, which can be seen below. Notice that the link state is DOWN for enp0s3, yet bond0 still has both IP addresses.
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master bond0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:8c:35:70 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:56:6b:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/eter 36:a3:66:28:36:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.10/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global bond0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.0.3.10/24 brd 10.0.3.255 scope global bond0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::34a3:66ff:fe28:36e3/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

The routing table hasn't changed:
$ ip route
default via 10.0.2.2 dev bond0 proto kernel scope lin src 10.0.2.10
default via 10.0.3.2 dev bond0 proto kernel scope lin src 10.0.3.10

$ ip route show table all
default via 10.0.2.2 dev bond0 table 100 proto static metric 100
default via 10.0.3.2 dev bond0 table 200 proto static metric 200
10.0.2.0/24 dev bond0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.10
10.0.3.0/24 dev bond0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.10
local 10.0.2.10 dev bond0 table local proto kernel scope host src 10.0.2.10
broadcast 10.0.2.255 dev bond0 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.10
local 10.0.3.10 dev bond0 table local proto kernel scope host src 10.0.3.10
broadcast 10.0.3.255 dev bond0 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.10
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev bond0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
local 1 dev lo table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local fe80::34a3:66ff:fe28:36e3 dev bond0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
multicast ff00::/8 dev bond0 table local proto kernel metric 256 pref medium

However, when running a traceroute command while inspecting the interfaces with tcpdump, you'll notice the first hop is 10.0.3.2, and traffic is now routed to interface enp0s8 with nothing on enp0s3.
$ traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (10.0.3.2)  0.474 ms  0.387 ms  0.351 ms
 2  172.23.123.1 (172.23.123.1)  5.653 ms  5.624 ms  5.510 ms
 3  usa-67-224-97-97.sohonet.co.uk (67.224.97.97)  9.932 ms  7.214 ms  13.918 ms
 4  usa-173-0-160-145.sohonet.com (173.0.160.145)  5.226 ms  5.198 ms  5.121 ms
 5  soho185-116-57-52.sohonet.co.uk (185.116.57.52)  5.187 ms  5.118 ms  5.089 ms
 6  usa-67-224-111-33.sohonet.co.uk (67.224.111.33)  4.918 ms  3.492 ms  3.422 ms
 7  usa-67-224-111-32.sohonet.co.uk (67.224.111.32)  3.391 ms  3.300 ms  3.236 ms
 8  usa-67-224-111-10.sohonet.co.uk (67.224.111.10)  4.872 ms  6.056 ms  6.029 ms
 9  * * *
10  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  3.171 ms  3.139 ms  3.113 ms

$ sudo tcpdump -i enp0s3

$ sudo tcpdump -i enp0s8
04:43:56.185298 IP server.46830 > dns.google.33434: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.185363 IP server.57264 > dns.google.33435: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.185396 IP server.56908 > dns.google.33436: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.185425 IP server.42462 > dns.google.33437: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.185457 IP server.57764 > dns.google.33438: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.185496 IP server.39777 > dns.google.33439: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.185535 IP server.44911 > dns.google.33440: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.185571 IP server.56881 > dns.google.33441: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.185609 IP server.41380 > dns.google.33442: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.185647 IP server.40657 > dns.google.33443: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.185686 IP server.36257 > dns.google.33444: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.185737 IP server.37273 > dns.google.33445: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.185763 IP 10.0.3.2 > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 36
04:43:56.185763 IP 10.0.3.2 > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 36
04:43:56.185764 IP 10.0.3.2 > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 36
04:43:56.185787 IP server.57713 > dns.google.33446: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.185818 IP server.53892 > dns.google.33447: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.185860 IP server.43699 > dns.google.33448: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.185891 IP server.32859 > dns.google.33449: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.186614 IP server.57198 > dns.google.domain: 13266+ [1au] PTR? 2.3.0.10.in-addr.arpa. (50)
04:43:56.190257 IP 172.23.123.1 > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
04:43:56.190257 IP 172.23.123.1 > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
04:43:56.191212 IP soho185-116-57-52.sohonet.co.uk > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 152
04:43:56.191212 IP 172.23.123.1 > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
04:43:56.191212 IP usa-173-0-160-145.sohonet.com > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
04:43:56.191307 IP usa-173-0-160-145.sohonet.com > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
04:43:56.191307 IP usa-173-0-160-145.sohonet.com > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
04:43:56.191307 IP usa-67-224-111-33.sohonet.co.uk > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
04:43:56.193100 IP soho185-116-57-52.sohonet.co.uk > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 152
04:43:56.193100 IP dns.google.domain > server.57198: 13266 NXDomain 0/0/1 (50)
04:43:56.193100 IP soho185-116-57-52.sohonet.co.uk > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 152
04:43:56.193100 IP usa-67-224-97-97.sohonet.co.uk > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 40
04:43:56.193269 IP server.57198 > dns.google.domain: 13266+ PTR? 2.3.0.10.in-addr.arpa. (39)
04:43:56.195017 IP usa-67-224-97-97.sohonet.co.uk > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 40
04:43:56.196039 IP dns.google.domain > server.57198: 13266 NXDomain 0/0/0 (39)
04:43:56.196599 IP server.50638 > dns.google.33450: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.196653 IP server.48481 > dns.google.33451: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.196687 IP server.56321 > dns.google.33452: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.197133 IP server.40630 > dns.google.domain: 10311+ [1au] PTR? 1.123.23.172.in-addr.arpa. (54)
04:43:56.197212 IP usa-67-224-97-97.sohonet.co.uk > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 40
04:43:56.200279 IP usa-67-224-111-32.sohonet.co.uk > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
04:43:56.200279 IP usa-67-224-111-33.sohonet.co.uk > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
04:43:56.200279 IP usa-67-224-111-33.sohonet.co.uk > server: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 68
04:43:56.200279 IP dns.google.domain > server.40630: 10311 NXDomain 0/0/1 (54)
04:43:56.200408 IP server.40630 > dns.google.domain: 10311+ PTR? 1.123.23.172.in-addr.arpa. (43)
04:43:56.203682 IP dns.google.domain > server.40630: 10311 NXDomain 0/0/0 (43)
04:43:56.205124 IP server.50912 > dns.google.33453: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.205174 IP server.54998 > dns.google.33454: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.205217 IP server.57651 > dns.google.33455: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.205249 IP server.37953 > dns.google.33456: UDP, length 32
04:43:56.205291 IP server.47998 > dns.goo




Netplan config without a bond interface
Configuring your server so that one interface takes precedence and the other serves as a backup can also be done without a bond interface by simply defining two interfaces and setting the metric value for the primary interface to take priority. All traffic will be routed out the primary interface, yet if the primary interface goes down, traffic will be routed out the secondary interface.
As an example, I created a VM in VirtualBox with two interfaces, each on different subnets. My Netplan .yaml file is as follows. Notice that the metric for enp0s3 is 100 and for enp0s8 it's 200. A lower value takes precedence.
$ sudo cat 00-custom-config.yaml 
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses:
        - 10.0.2.10/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 10.0.2.2
          metric: 100
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses:
        - 10.0.3.10/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 10.0.3.2
          metric: 200

With both links up, each has an IP address:
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:8c:35:70 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.10/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global enp0s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe8c:3570/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:56:6b:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.3.10/24 brd 10.0.3.255 scope global enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe56:6b6b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

The routes generated from Netplan are as follows:
$ ip route
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto static metric 100
default via 10.0.3.2 dev enp0s8 proto static metric 200
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.10
10.0.3.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.10

If I run traceroute 8.8.8.8, you'll see that the first hop is 10.0.2.2, which is the default route via interface enp0s3. This is because this route has a lower metric value of 100 versus the metric value of 200 associated with the default route to 10.0.3.2 via enp0s8.
$ traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (10.0.2.2)  0.443 ms  0.382 ms  0.356 ms
 2  172.23.123.1 (172.23.123.1)  6.054 ms  6.024 ms  5.999 ms
 3  usa-67-224-97-97.sohonet.co.uk (67.224.97.97)  8.575 ms  12.017 ms  9.610 ms
 4  usa-173-0-160-145.sohonet.com (173.0.160.145)  6.469 ms  5.697 ms  5.656 ms
 5  soho185-116-57-52.sohonet.co.uk (185.116.57.52)  7.052 ms  5.586 ms  6.975 ms
 6  usa-67-224-111-33.sohonet.co.uk (67.224.111.33)  5.510 ms  7.741 ms  7.680 ms
 7  usa-67-224-111-32.sohonet.co.uk (67.224.111.32)  7.650 ms  6.140 ms  6.063 ms
 8  usa-67-224-111-10.sohonet.co.uk (67.224.111.10)  6.016 ms  5.982 ms  6.013 ms
 9  * * *
10  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  5.707 ms  5.672 ms  5.645 ms

To simulate the interface going down, I can uncheck the Cable Connected box within VirtualBox for the first interface, which is enp0s3:

After hitting "OK", the interface will be down, which can be seen below. Notice that the link state is DOWN for enp0s3 and it does not have an IP address.
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:8c:35:70 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe8c:3570/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:56:6b:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.3.10/24 brd 10.0.3.255 scope global enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe56:6b6b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Checking the routing table, there's only one default route now, which is to 10.0.3.2 via interface enp0s8.
$ ip route
default via 10.0.3.2 dev enp0s8 proto static metric 200
10.0.3.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.10 

And finally, running traceroute 8.8.8.8 shows that the first hop is 10.0.3.2, which is via interface enp0s8 and not enp0s3:
$ traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (10.0.3.2)  0.474 ms  0.387 ms  0.351 ms
 2  172.23.123.1 (172.23.123.1)  5.653 ms  5.624 ms  5.510 ms
 3  usa-67-224-97-97.sohonet.co.uk (67.224.97.97)  9.932 ms  7.214 ms  13.918 ms
 4  usa-173-0-160-145.sohonet.com (173.0.160.145)  5.226 ms  5.198 ms  5.121 ms
 5  soho185-116-57-52.sohonet.co.uk (185.116.57.52)  5.187 ms  5.118 ms  5.089 ms
 6  usa-67-224-111-33.sohonet.co.uk (67.224.111.33)  4.918 ms  3.492 ms  3.422 ms
 7  usa-67-224-111-32.sohonet.co.uk (67.224.111.32)  3.391 ms  3.300 ms  3.236 ms
 8  usa-67-224-111-10.sohonet.co.uk (67.224.111.10)  4.872 ms  6.056 ms  6.029 ms
 9  * * *
10  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  3.171 ms  3.139 ms  3.113 ms


Thank you very much for your answer but I still have issue, just for verification did you separate Virtual Network (LAN segment) on your VirtualBox setting?

In VirtualBox, each interface was setup as NAT. As a result, one interface was on 10.0.2.0/24 and the other was on 10.0.3.0/24. So effectively two different networks. And BTW, I tested on Ubuntu 22.04 and 24.04. Also, it was finicky. I found that a full reboot was needed instead of a simple restarting of systemd-networkd.

The Virtual Machine is private and I don't have access to vCenter in our home, It's weekend in our Iran and I'll will try rebooting my VM in the day after tomorrow, Thank you for your kind response, If I succeed I will comment it here and notify you.

Once again thank you for your answer, unfortunate didn't work and I don't know why, I reboot and check and read logs but I didn't know why :( I installed Mikrotik CHR and fixed it from there, I'll hope someday I be able to  bond networks from GNU/Linux machine.
